# Chrome extension crash after immediate install

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My application performs an inline installation of my chrome extension (assuming it's not installed).  After the user has installed the extension my application then sends it's first message to the extension.

```
factory.messageExtension = function (newPost) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $window.postMessage({
        'cmd': 'create',
        'data': newPost
    }, "*");

    deferred.resolve();

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` is thrown at line `316` of `@extensions::messaging:`

`if (port.name != kNativeMessageChannel)...`

The full call stack is:

```
sendMessageImpl @   extensions::messaging:316
(anonymous function)    @   extensions::runtime:115
target.(anonymous function) @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
(anonymous function)    @   extensions::binding:57
target.(anonymous function) @   extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
(anonymous function)    @   extensions::binding:385
(anonymous function)    @   inject.js:17
```

I've debugged all the way down to line `383` of `@extensions::binding` and found that `retval` is undefined when it should be equal to `Port = {}`

Just so we're clear here is what retval is equal to if the extension is already installed.
[image]

But when the extension is NOT already installed and therefore asks the user to install the extension THEN it sends a message to the extension here is what we see:

[image]

Here is manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "crypto - crypto",
    "short_name": "crypto",
    "version": "0.2",
    "homepage_url": "https://www.placeholder.com",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/48x48.png"
    },

    "icons": {
        "16" : "icons/16x16.png",
        "48" : "icons/48x48.png",
        "128" : "icons/128x128.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/mootools-core-1.3.1.js",
            "js/common.js",
            "js/background.js",
            "js/categories.js",
            "js/locations.js",
            "js/authentication.js"
        ]
    },


    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["*://localhost/*"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs", 
        "<all_urls>",
        "*://*/*"
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/*"
    ],

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/mootools-core-1.3.1.js",
            "js/mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js",
            "js/common.js",
            "js/autoposter.js",
            "js/inject.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

Here is background.js listeners

```
//this listens for messages from inject
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(ext.handleInjectMessages);

//this watches the button in the chrome's chrome
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(ext.clickedIcon);

//this watches for the tab to close
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(ext.handleTabClose);

//this listens for request to check version of extension from external application
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(ext.checkVersion);


// Check whether new version is installed
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    if(details.reason == "install"){
        console.log("This is a first install!");
    }else if(details.reason == "update"){
        var thisVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
        console.log("Updated from " + details.previousVersion + " to " + thisVersion + "!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in your code and there's no need to debug the built-in javascript wrappers. If I am not mistaken the error occurs because the communication channel is closed midway. Show the code that listens to the external messages in your extension like `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` or `.onConnectExternal`.

Comment: Also it's not clear if your application sends the message from a webpage that the installation package opens (show us the relevant parts of manifest.json like `"externally_connectable"`) or something else.

Comment: The code that you've shown does not relate to the error that you're getting. `window.postMessage` is different from the `postMessage` method of an extension message port.

Comment: @wOxxom, sorry for delay and thanks for your help, I've added the code your requested to the post. The webpage that installs the extension is also the webpage that needs to talk to the extension immediately after install.  The code the extension injects into the webpage isn't added to this webpage unless the page is refreshed.  This is basically the issue.  I don't want to have to reload the page after the extension is installed.

Comment: To receive a message from a webpage it should be listed in `"externally_connectable"` and it should use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage("asdfasfdafsdf", ......)` where `asdfasfdafsdf` is your extension ID. I don't see it in your code. Also local webpages with `file://` URLs aren't the same as `localhost`...

Comment: I've also observed crashes after doing inline installs. I thank you for sharing this, as it may help me identify the cause.